# How to import cmake project in swift-based ios project like JNI?

Tags: c++, ios, swift

### background

- I have a cmake project (c++), which is complicated and well written, so I don't want to modify it.
- I want to use some functions of this project in an IOS APP.

## Target

- I want to link it with an IOS project in swift, just like what JNI does in android project.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Cmake is just a build system, it has little to do with language interoperability.

Comment: Yes, you can integrate C++ code into an iOS project written in Swift by using Objective-C++ as a bridge. Objective-C++ is a programming language that allows C++ code to be used within Objective-C source files.